# Was ist das Verb, das den Akkusativ in diesem elidierten Satz vorschreibt: »Auf welchen Namen, bitte?«

Tags: word-choice

Von Foreign Services Institute U.S. Department of State German Course 1946 Im Restaurant:

> A. Guten Abend. Wir haben für halb sieben einen Tisch reserviert.
>
> N. Guten Abend. **Auf welchen Namen**, bitte?
>
> A. Kowalsky, für sechs Personen.

Ich glaube es ist nicht reservieren. Was passt?

»Auf« kann sowohl Dativ als auch Akkusativ verlangen, hier ist es der Akkusativ. Ich denke ein Verb, das hier fehlt, ist der Grund. Könnte jemand ein Wort vorschlagen?

Comment: Wer oder was ist »FSI«? Bitte bei Abkürzungen, die nicht alltäglich sind, immer auch die Langform angeben!

Comment: Passt das Verb "buchen"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Präposition "auf" kann mit dem Dativ und dem Akkusativ benutzt werden, allerdings mit unterschiedlicher Bedeutung. In diesem Fall braucht sie den Akkusativ, weil sich die Reservierung auf den Namen bezieht.

Der Dativ würde implizieren, dass das "auf" eine räumliche Position (z.B. *auf dem Tisch*) oder ein Ereignis (*auf der Weihnachtsfeier*) beschreibt, was in diesem Zudammenhang nicht gemeint ist.

Grammatisch korrekt könnte man auch fragen: "Auf *welchem* Namen haben Sie reserviert?", um sich z.B. nach dem Ort der Reservierung zu erkundigen, wenn etwa verschiedene Namen auf dem Boden aufgedruckt wären und die Reservierung an der Position eines bestimmten Namens stattgefunden hätte. Es macht halt inhaltlich keinen Sinn.

Comment: *Auf welchem Namen ... reserviert* habe ich noch nie gehört. Wenn es der Dativ sein soll, dann vielleicht *Unter welchem Namen*. Gibt es eine Quelle für die Richtigkeit?

Comment: Wie ich schrieb, macht das inhaltlich/semantisch keinen Sinn. *Niemand* würde das so sagen. Aber rein von der Grammatik her ist es zulässig - es hätte eben die Bedeutung, dass ein Name irgendwie z.B. als Ort funktionieren müsste (z.B. indem es Podeste mit der Aufschrift "Meier", "Müller" und "Schmitz" gäbe) und danach gefragt ist, von welchem dieser Orte aus die Reservierung getätigt wurde. Natürlich ist das völliger Mumpitz, aber der Grammatik ist das egal.